# how to use update statement for updating more than two rows at a time in linq

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

I have a table and I need to update 2 rows at a time.

My SQL query will look like this:

```
UPDATE tablename SET columnname=value WHERE tablename.id in (1,2)
```

I need the same in LINQ.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: its may be help to u.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10314552/how-to-update-the-multiple-rows-at-a-time-using-linq-to-sql
 thank you

Comment: already asked http://stackoverflow.com/a/10314666/17447 with a very detailed answer.

Comment: LINQ is a *query* language, not an update language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such thing in LINQ to SQL. It will Always update one row at a time.

Of course, you can do a

```
foreach (var key in keys)
{
var r = db.Table.Single(i=>i.ID == key);
r.xyz = value;
}
db.submitchanges()
```

But essentially this will update each row with a single update statement. In a transaction, nonetheless so it will achieve the same as your update statement but with a significant performance penalty depending on the number of records