# LINQ to SQL update all records

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I have a table like this:

[image]

I want to update Seasonal_Voucher column for all users with something

like : `UPDATE Users SET Seasonal_Voucher = 'Something'`

I tried this but it wont work:

```
using (DataClassesDataContext context = new DataClassesDataContext())
{
    Users use = context.Users;
    {
        use.Seasonal_Voucher =DropDownList1.SelectedItem.ToString();
    };
    context.Refresh(0);
    context.SubmitChanges();
}
```

Comment: Define "it won't work." Compile errors? Runtime errors? Nothing happens?

Comment: Are you sure this is LINQ to SQL? Looks like entity framework.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Sami suggested in the comments, "it won't work" is too broad. However, here is a basic modification of your code: (since you tagged linq also, I assume you are familiar with lambda syntax)

```
using (DataClassesDataContext context = new DataClassesDataContext())
{
    foreach (var use in context.Users)
    {
        use.Seasonal_Voucher = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.ToString();
    };
    //context.Refresh(0);
    //context.SubmitChanges();
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

I realize (as Rob mentions) that loading the entire table into memory for updating is not wise. As such, you could simply try the `ExecuteSqlCommand` method (since it looks like you're using Entity Framework anyways). MSDN: [Database.ExecuteSqlCommand Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.database.executesqlcommand(v=vs.113).aspx)

It is useful for bulk updates.

```
string sqlQuery = "UPDATE Users SET Seasonal_Voucher = '" + DropDownList1.SelectedItem.ToString() + "'";
using (DataClassesDataContext context = new DataClassesDataContext())
{
    context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(sqlQuery);
}
```

Comment: The question title explicitly says they want to update *all* records. Thus, the where is unneeded. And loading the entire table into memory is not ideal when what you're *really* trying to do is a bulk update

Comment: @Rob You're right, I've edited my answer with a better way as alternative.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively with reference to [how to update the multiple rows at a time using linq to sql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10314552/how-to-update-the-multiple-rows-at-a-time-using-linq-to-sql)
Below code does the same. However as its mentioned by Keyur, entire table will be loaded for the update operation which would be a performance bottleneck.

```
using (DataClassesDataContext context = new DataClassesDataContext())
{
   var users= context.Users.ToList();
    users.ForEach(user=>user.Seasonal_Voucher=DropDownList1.SelectedItem.ToString());
   context.SaveChanges();

}
```

or

```
using (DataClassesDataContext context = new DataClassesDataContext())
{
   context.Users.ToList().ForEach(user=>user.Seasonal_Voucher=DropDownList1.SelectedItem.ToString());
   context.SaveChanges();   
}
```