# LINQ Query ForEach cannot use

Tags: c#, linq, foreach

I have a LINQ "result" of anonymuosType, inside it, it have some entity object which query by LINQ from EF.

I would like to make used of the "result" to filter and set some new value on the entity object for the "newResult".

But I not able to use the ForEach(), after the .Where() on "newResult".

May I know what I did wrong? Any alternative solution by using LINQ? 
(I can do simple foreach looping to achieve it, But I would like to learn more by using LINQ.)

```
var result = (from e in unmatch_epay_details
                                   join w in DB.WatReconDetails
                                   on e.RetTransRef equals w.RetTransRef
                                   into a
                                   from b in a.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                   select new
                                   {
                                       ePayDetailID = e.ePayReconDetailID,
                                       WATStatus = (b == default(WatReconDetail)) ? 0 : 1,//** if default return 0.
                                       EpayInfo = e,
                                       WATinfo = b
                                   })
                                   .OrderBy(a => a.ServerTransDateTime)
                                  .ToList();


var newResult = result
        .Where(a => a.EpayInfo.condition =="condition")
        .ForEach(b => b.EpayInfo.result=="result");//I not able to use the foreach at here.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ForEach()` is not linq, it is a function on `List<T>` (and you are working with `IEnumerable<T>`).
So use normal `foreach` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Like others have pointed out, ForEach works on Lists but not on IEnumerables. You can define your own ForEach extension that works on IEnumerable like this

```
 public static class MyExtension
 {
      public static void ForEach<T>(this IEnumerable<T> data, Action<T> action)
      {
            foreach (T element in data)
            {
                 action(element);
            }
      }
 }
```